# Getting error while sending json data from controller to view in codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax, codeigniter

previously I was sending a single value from controller to view and it was successfully got. Now I want to send two values by using `JSON` data.

**Controller**

```
$batch_wise_stock =  sprintf('%0.2f',(!empty($pur_product_batch->purchase_qty)?$pur_product_batch->purchase_qty:0)-(!empty($sellt_prod_batch->sale_qty)?$sellt_prod_batch->sale_qty:0));
    $batch_wise_rate = $pur_product_batch->rate;
   
    $json_product[] = array('qty'=>$batch_wise_stock,'rate'=>$batch_wise_rate);
           echo json_encode($json_product);
```

**AJAX**

```
$.ajax( {
        url: base_url + "invoice/invoice/batchwise_productprice",
        method: 'post',
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
        prod_id: prod_id,
        batch_no:batch_no,
        csrf_test_name:csrf_test_name,
        },
        success: function( data ) {
            var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            console.log(obj);
            if (parseInt(data) >= 0) {
                $(".available_quantity_" + sl).val(data.toFixed(2,2));
            }else{
                var message = "You can Sale maximum " + available_quantity + " Items";
                toastr["error"](message);
                $("#total_qntt_" + sl).val('');
                var quantity = 0;
                $("#total_price_" + sl).val(0);
                for(var i=0;i<taxnumber;i++){
                    $("#all_tax"+i+"_" + sl).val(0);
                    
                }
            }
           
        }
      });
```

**error**

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? How does the generated output look like? I would assume that it contains any unwanted data. Also, is this problem really related to jQuery or AJAX? If the server generates invalid markup, this does not look related to these two techniques to me

Comment: Look at the response in the Network tab of your browser's Developer console. Does it look like valid JSON, or is it throwing an error?

Comment: @NicoHaase if I `echo $batch_wise_stock;` or `echo $batch_wise_rate` then I am able to see the desired output. but `echo json_encode($json_product);` gives me this error

Comment: @aynber it's giving me `200` status

Comment: Response, not status.

Comment: @aynber yes response

Comment: No, my question is, what is the full response from the request in the Network tab? 200 is the status, but not the body of the response.

Comment: See what you've got in the ajax success with `console.dir(data)` and take it from there

Comment: In `Response tab` I am getting `Object { qty: "8.00", rate: "400.00" }`

Comment: then `data.qty` and `data.rate` should do

Comment: `data.qty` and `data.rate` is giving me `undefined`

Comment: It should not show `Object` in the response, just `{ qty: "8.00", rate: "400.00" }`. So you have some extra information being printed from somewhere

Comment: It's been awhile since I used codeIgniter, but I'm not sure you need to json decode data.

Comment: Additionally, do you have an `exit` statement after the `echo` in the controller?

Comment: since you `$json_product[] = array(..etc..)` you might need `data[0].qty`. Anyway again, what does `console.dir(data)` spit out in the console tab?

Comment: @Vickel it gives `0: {qty: '500.00', rate: '400.00'}`. while `$(".available_quantity_" + sl).val(data[0].qty.toFixed(2,2));` gives me `Uncaught TypeError: data[0].qty.toFixed is not a function`

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Don't hide your debugging attempts in the comment section

Answer (score 0):

Try looping through your returned data... (then compare with obj later)

```
$.each(data, function(index, value ){
    $('#item_qty' + sl).val(value.qty); //console.log() or alert();
    $("#item_price" + sl).val(value.rate);
});
```